# Proxifier that supports UDP?

Tags: drivers, proxy, udp

Im looking for a proxifier that forces all Windows traffic through a specific proxy. I have my own server so I can ultimately configure any type of proxy (Socks, HTTPS, etc) so thats not a problem, although HTTPS supported is preferred as I like squid.

One of the biggest problems I've been having is finding a proxy program that supports UDP connections. My favorite is probably Proxifier ( http://proxifier.com/ ) it works amazingly, but it doesn't support UDP for ANY type of proxy.

Specifically, I'm trying to get the proxy to work for my games (which obviously, use UDP)

Any type of injection proxy program will not work - I need one that redirects all general traffic using a network driver or similar. (unless you can guarantee that a similar injection program will work for most 99% of FPS games on the PC)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't proxy UDP, simply because unlike TCP, UDP is a connectionless protocol.  A proxy relies on you making a connection to the proxy server, that proxy server making the request on your behalf, and then returning the data back to you.

What you need to do is rewrite the packets as they go through your firewall.  NAT usually does this for you.  Your firewall will also have to support SPI - Stateful Packet Inspection so it keeps a record of the UDP flow so that return traffic comes back to the right machine.

If you are unable to adjust the firewall that is between you and the internet then a VPN is by far the simplest way to go.  There are many different ways to create a VPN using many different technologies.  The right one depends entirely on a) what you are happy configuring, and b) what your firewall will allow through and c) What your client machine is capable of running.

Comment: Thankyou for the information - have any non OpenVPN VPN suggestions?

Comment: Hamachi is particularly easy to set up - you just add computers to your network in a similar fashion to adding a buddy to an IM client.

Comment: And after confiquring hamachi, i could route all of my internet traffic through that? i didnt think it worked that way.

Comment: Heh, what a difference 6 minutes makes.

Comment: @PriceChild He gave me an answer as to WHY, you didnt.

Comment: My 'why' was that I thought you didn't fully understand the terminology used, hence suggesting 'vpn' over 'proxy'. I was hoping that was simply implied. If you were wanting to know the difference between a vpn and a proxy then there's a question for that http://superuser.com/questions/257388/what-is-the-difference-between-a-proxy-and-a-vpn EDIT: heh, with an accepted answer by our very own Matt Jenkins!

Comment: I have been nice and countered the downvote with an upvote... ;)

Comment: Meh, locked in after 5 minutes, didn't know about that feature. Hey ho.

Comment: Wrong, Socks5 supports UDP ASSOCIATE, that allows UDP data trough a proxy.

Comment: What you have written about how proxying udp is "impossible", makes absolutely no sense.  Try `nc -ul 1234 | nc 5.6.7.8`   you also haven't even responded to Eun.  I am no expert, but I think you're wrong.  I will remove my downvote if you show me i'm wrong.

Comment: Socks5 is not a proxy. Neither is creating a pipe with nc. Socks5 is a different protocol which instructs a remote. Computer to make connections on your behalf and a netcat pipe is just that, a single pipe. While nc would work for a single  person making a single connection it cannot work for multiple people making multiple connections, which it would have to do to be considered a proxy.

Comment: I am not sure this comment, or answer makes sense, a proxy is defined as "any machine that translates traffic between networks or protocols.", you can argue that there's no direct address translation, so not a proxy, however that is way too nitpicky, you are using one machine to reach another machine, it is a proxy by the definition of the word itself; I see no reason not to call a SOCKS5 server a proxy server, even RFCs mention  using UDP through proxies.

Answer (score 3):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers

Under section "Proxy protocols and methods", look at the column 'UDP Associate'.

WideCap is now freeware and runs on PC.  URL: http://widecap.com/

I have not tested it for how well it handles UDP.

EDIT: I followed up and tested WideCap.  The configuration system is a bit clunky, but it does conform to SOCKS5 standard including the UDP associate function.  Connected to an AntiNAT server in Socks5 mode it allowed a non proxy-aware application TCP and UDP connectivity without issue other than being somewhat slow.

Note: As I understand it, it only works for client software.  It doesn't look like you can hang a server with LISTEN ports behind Socks5 and receive incoming connections.

Comment: EDIT 2:  Widecap application compatibility didn't do well in further testing here.  The technique of hooking into a programs network calls seems hit or miss.  I had better compatibility results with Sockscap64 (http://www.sockscap64.com/en/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for a 'vpn' instead? https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/OpenVPN seems to be a free, multi-platform example if you can set up the server software on the other end.

Comment: i have looked at vpn's - i had some severe firewall problems, and didnt have enough linux experience to set it up. maybe i will still look into it some more, however that is not a legitimate answer for the question and perhaps should have been posted as a comment.

Comment: I'm quite confident it is a legitimate answer. I don't think a 'proxy' is what you think it is. See the second last result on https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=define%3A+proxy (Other definitions on that page don't contradict this, but don't make the same definition)