# Why google.com doesn't use HTTP proxy that I set up?

Tags: google-chrome

I configured my http proxy to Chrome browser using Proxifier.

All sites are connecting thru the proxy, but google.com doesn't.

For example, if I type what's my ip on google search it provides me my actual IP.

This is not the case with IE. I also checked Firefox and it has same behavior.

Comment: it's pretty trivial for a browser to deproxify itself if the proxy configuration is implemented at the browser level. a system level or network level proxy would probably not exhibit this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very educated guess - https://proxifier.com/features.html says proxifier "can process all outgoing TCP connections".   Most http/https connections are done on tcp port 443.

Google, however, have championed another way of doing things.  Their QUIC protocol uses UDP rather then TCP for the very small handful of web servers that have this supported and enabled.   I posit that proxifier is intercepting TCP connections but Google is using UDP and thus bypassing Proxyfier.  ([Proxifier that supports UDP?](https://superuser.com/questions/264486/proxifier-that-supports-udp) would appear to be relevant)

If you are able to block UDP traffic on your router you can test this theory (where QUIC does not work, the browser automatically falls back to a regular TCP connection)

Comment: Thanks, David. I thought about QUIC and HTTP3 as-well as HTTP2 couple hours ago. I'm going to try to disable it on morning and re-check..

Comment: Disabled HTTP2 and QUIC. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Google may use newer QUIC and HTTP3 protocol which utilizes UDP connection instead of TCP/IP. In latest proxifer software you could select `block all traffic to UDP if matched by the rules` to enforce your proxy policy.